# Missing closing bracket

Tags: java, android, regex

Missing closing bracket in character class near index 13
|\?*<":>+[]/'
My code:

```
Pattern.compile("|\\?*<\":>+[]/'").matcher(name).matches()
```

Comment: The square brackets have nothing inside them. Java thinks that you haven't ended the square brackets

Comment: most of your characters need to be escaped if you want to use them as characters and not modifiers/alternators/etc.

Comment: Please tell us what you'd like to match.

Comment: In Java, a ``\`` is never just a ``\"`` (except when it is). Regular expressions and ``\`` is a nightmare.

Comment: all chars inside ```"``` from ```|``` to ```'```

Comment: You can find plenty of website to try and test you regex here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Pattern.compile("[|\\\\?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']+").matcher(name).matches()
```

The regex means:

- `[` - start of a positive character class:

  - `|` - a pipe
  - `\\` - a backslash (requires additional backslashes in the string literal, `"\\\\"`)
  - `?` - a question mark
  - `*` - an asterisk
  - `<` - an open angle bracket
  - `"` - a double quotationmark
  - `:` - a colon
  - `>` -  a close angle bracket
  - `+` - a plus
  - `\[`  - a `[` char (must be escaped when `[` is inside a character class)
  - `\]` -  a `]` char (must be escaped when `]` is inside a character class)
  - `/` - a forward slash
  - `'` - a single quotation mark
- `]+` - end of character class, 1 or more occurrences.

So, this will validate a string that only consists of 1 or more occurrences of these chars. If you need the opposite, add `^` after the first `[`:

```
Pattern.compile("[^|\\\\?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']+").matcher(name).matches()
//                ^
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/GwWsCB):

```
String name = "Wiktor Stribiżew";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("[^|\\\\?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']+").matcher(name).matches());
// => true
```

Comment: I try this but my app still error. ```Pattern.compile("[^|\\?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']+").matcher(name).matches()```

Comment: @FajarNurP What app? Is it Java? Then [it works](https://ideone.com/GwWsCB). Post your code that does not.

Comment: @FajarNurP What is the issue now, if you use ``"[^|\\\\?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']+"``?

Comment: Yes, Java (Android). my app not force close but freze for long time

Comment: You did not use my code. Use `"[^|\\\\?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']+"`. Next, if the error you had is gone, the current question is answered.

Comment: I use your code but my app still freze Sir. Including my keyboard frezed to

Comment: My bad. Just need ```!``` inside ```if``` statement.